# Rails - Add a security key to Sign up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use a universal security key (a defined string) to my sign up page so that the users who are provided with it can sign up. This is to ensure that those who sign up are the intended people.

In my user schema, I have a string column "security_key" so that in the sign up page it can accept an input for the security key in my user Sign Up page. I am not sure how to implement this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want your key to be universal, in the signup form you just need to have a `text_field` to enter the provided security key.

then in your `registrations_controller`, you can:

```
before_action :validate_security_key

private

def validate_security_key
  head :forbidden and return unless params[:security_key] == ENV.fetch('SECURITY_KEY')
end
```

**Suggestion/Recommendation:**

There's no sense in making security key not secure i.e. universal. Since you are specific about people signing up, I suppose the `security_key` will be provided to them through email/text or some other medium, where you provide signup url to register, so I suggest to include that security key in the url itself as param and verify it in the app. e.g.:

In your mailer:

```
link_to new_user_sign_up_url + "?security_key=#{User.security_key(@email)}"
```

In your User model:

```
def security_key(email)
  Digest::SHA256.hexdigest "#{email}MySecuredKey#{ENV.fetch('UNIVERSAL_SECURITY_KEY')}"
end
```

and your before_action will change to:

```
def validate_security_key
  head :forbidden and return unless params[:security_key] == User.security_key(params[:email])
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create another table for storing the security key.
Then you can match the security key provided by the user at the time of registration. 
Maybe in you `regestration_controller`, add a `before_action` hook to invoke a method `check_security_key`.

```
def check_security_key
  unless SecurityKey.where(s_key: params[:security_key]).first.present?
     redirect_to signup_path
  end
end
```

This is just an idea. You can use any table name, column name.